# MapBox data out of date

Tags: mapbox

Not a programming question, but I know some MapBox people occasionally contribute here, and I'm keen for some (semi) official answers.

The MapBox base layer has not received new data from OSM since at least September 20 last year, when I made Changeset 52228037.

This is causing us some problems. I'm having to write node ID specific styles to hide things that no longer exist.

Is this not causing issues for others?
Does anyone know if there is there a timeline for restoration?

And I quote:

> We're on track to resume updates by the end of Q2, so you should be seeing updates by the end of June at the latest. However, if anything occurs sooner than that I'll be sure to circle back and reach out to you. Thank you for your continued patience!

It's more than a little bit frustrating.

I realised I'd asked almost exactly the same question last year: OSM changes not getting to MapBox? and received an almost identical response.

The area around our uni campus is currently experiencing huge construction disruptions, with 3 major projects in the space of a single block. So much has changed/moved/closed, but our maps can't show it. :-(

Comment: Yes, this is the question indeed! And paid accounts don't receive updates too, btw.